# Tensor Flow compilation in Visual Studio c++

Tags: c++, tensorflow, compilation, static-assert

I downloaded Tensor Flow by anaconda, set PATHs in the Visual studio C++ progect and trying to compile the "Hellow word" example from https://github.com/ksachdeva/tensorflow-cc-examples/blob/master/examples/1_Introduction/src/hello-world.cc.

It gives me three errors in "tensorflow\core\framework\types.h":

Code    Description Project Line
C2338   static_assert failed: 'NOT good type'   ConsoleApplication1 357
C2039   'v': is not a member of 'tensorflow::DataTypeToEnumstd::string'   ConsoleApplication1 863
C3861   'v': identifier not found   ConsoleApplication1 862

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you in advance!

I tried to make minor changes in the "types.h", project proprties (/permissive, /permissive-), but it doesn't help. Possibly, I should take another version of Tensor Flow (I have the last version of the Visual Studio 2022)?